# How to get new value (:new.column) while using delete trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, database-trigger

I am using a delete trigger. I wanted to get both the old value and new value of a particular column in a new table. I tried using `:old.columnname` and `:new.columnname`. `:old.columnname` is working fine, but `:new.columnnam`e is not working. That column is filled with null in the new table. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

There are no "useful" `:new` values in a `delete` trigger.  The "new" record does not exist conceptually.  That is what `delete` does:  remove the "new" record.  The `:new` is there, but all the columns are `NULL`.

So, you should just use the `NULL` constant.

Comment: In a DELETE trigger there is a :NEW pseudo-row, but all the fields in the :NEW pseudo-row are NULL. [db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fbd1a125419348a455b1cfb6a4af7b5e)

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica . . . That is a good point.  I have clarified the answer.  I was trying to say that delete removes the "new" record so it is not there conceptually and it doesn't really make sense to refer to it.